# Error with Redux 4.0.0 while using @angular-redux/store

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, angular-redux

**Getting following error on compile time:**

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular-redux/store/lib/src/components/ng-redux.d.ts(10,31): error TS2420: Class 'NgRedux<RootState>' incorrectly implements interface 'ObservableStore<RootState>'.
  Types of property 'dispatch' are incompatible.
    Type 'Dispatch<RootState>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<AnyAction>'.
      Type 'RootState' is not assignable to type 'AnyAction'.
node_modules/@angular-redux/store/lib/src/components/ng-redux.d.ts(37,33): error TS2344: Type 'RootState' does not satisfy the constraint 'Action<any>'.
node_modules/@angular-redux/store/lib/src/components/root-store.d.ts(18,24): error TS2344: Type 'RootState' does not satisfy the constraint 'Action<any>'.
```

**Environment Setup:**

NodeJS Version: 8.9.1

Typescript Version: 2.8.1

Angular Version: 5.0.0

@angular-redux/store version: 7.1.1

OS: Windows 10

Comment: can you please add your code

Comment: Add code and also you are `RootState` type where as `AnyAction` is expected.

Comment: More specifically please show `ng-redux.d.ts`. Why did you need to build this type defn?

Answer (score 1):

The @angular-redux/store github page confirms this as a bug and will be fixed in future releases.

Downgrading Redux version from 4.0.0 to 3.7.0 resolved the issue as of now.